# "move" an object between lists in classes

Tags: python

i have a "simulated surgery" in python to program but dont know how.
 Here is my code:

```
class Surgery:
    def __init__(self):
        self.waitingroom = []
        self.office = []

    def enter_surgery(self, p):
        self.waitingroom.append(p)

    def call_next_patient(self):
        self.office.append
        self.waitingroom.remove

    def in_treatment(self):
        if self.office == []:
            return None
        else:
            return self.office

    def treatment_done(self):
        self.office.remove
```

As you can see i want to move the patient in "call_next_patient" from the waitingroom to the office, but with "self" it is not global. without self it tells me that waitingroom is not defindet. how can i manage it?

Comment: Do you want `self.office.append(self.waitingroom.pop())`?

Comment: Thank you that worked. But is there a way i can acces the first added object not the last one? EDIT: ah ok i get it, just add the "0" self.waitingroom.pop(0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `pop` and `append`.

From Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.pop([i])
>   Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in the list. (The square brackets around the i in the method signature denote that the parameter is optional, not that you should type square brackets at that position. You will see this notation frequently in the Python Library Reference.)

So,

```
def call_next_patient(self):
    patient = self.office.pop()
    self.waitingroom.append(patient)
```

Or in one statement:

```
def call_next_patient(self):
    self.waitingroom.append(self.office.pop())
```

Keep in mind that `.pop` raises an `IndexError` if the list is empty, so you will also need to use `try-except`:

```
def call_next_patient(self):
    try:
        self.waitingroom.append(self.office.pop())
    except IndexError:
        print('No waiting patients')
```

Comment: Thank you, looks good.
But also when i have items in the list it gives me the IndexError